# How would I show voice hours in server and messages sent in server in my !!userinfo command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my userinfo command where you can do it for any user and show voice hours in server and messages sent in server 
here is my !!userinfo command

```
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member,
  user = member.user;

  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.username)
    .setDescription("Users Info")
    .setColor("#9B59B6")
    .addField("Full Username:", `${message.author.username}${message.author.discriminator}`)
    .addField("ID:", message.author.id)
    .addField("Created at:", message.author.createdAt)
    .addField("Status:", `${user.presence.status}`)
    .addField("Game:", `${user.presence.game}`)
    .addField("Roles", member.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join('|'), true);

  message.channel.send(embed);        
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "userinfo"
}
```

How would I show voice hours and messages sent? Would I have to use SQL to record it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to record/save all of it yes, either with SQL or in some local JSON file. For Voice hours you'd need to listen to the [voiceStateUpdate event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) and save when a user joins and when a user leaves a voice channel. Then you'd calculate the time inbetween those timeframes and add it to the total amount of voice hours for said user.

For messages you'd just need to listen to the [message event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) and increment a counter for that specific user each time.